# Get Rubymine to recognize webpacker.yml config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, rubymine, webpacker

Is there a way to get Rubymine to process the webpacker.yml config file to properly setup roots and the like?  I think I can manually set a directory as a root for doing javascript imports but I'd really like to be able to have rubymine import the config automatically.

I'm open to ripping out webpacker.yml and replacing it with a javascript based config if necessary.

Comment: If you need JS imports then it's probably worth creating jsconfig (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) or webpack. If you want RubyMine to automatically setup roots then it'd be better to create a corresponding feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY

Comment: Yah, well in rails the interface to webpack is via webpacker which is what's causing the issue and my other question about how to use rails while ripping out webpacker is still unaswered but I figured out how to manually add roots so I'll just submit a request.  Thanks for the info!